# IIS 7 - Erro 403 Proibido: acesso negado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

Tenho um webservice `restfull` e quando depuro na minha máquina com meu Visual Studio ele funciona normalmente, mas quando publico no meu servidor de produção com `IIS 7` ele dá um erro de acesso negado. Meu projeto está em `mvc`, mas se eu coloco uma página teste na raiz do meu projeto no servidor, a página teste abre normalmente.

Simplesmente se coloco uma pagina em HTML na pasta onde estou publicando o projeto, ele abre a página mostrando que não é problema de autenticação no servidor, porém quando publico meu restfull mvc ele dá o erro:

> 403 - Proibido: acesso negado.

Estou usando autenticação anônima, framework `4.5`, estou subindo o projeto por `ftp` no *publish* do Visual Studio e meu `iis` está em uma máquina `win 8`.

Comment: Esqueci de falar, estou utilizando autenticação anonima!

Comment: Você configurou o IIS para aceitar acessos anônimos?

Comment: É servidor próprio? Ou usas algum provedor?

Comment: Servidor próprio!

Comment: O erro apresentado é 403.14 ?

Comment: não somente 403 mesmo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri o erro estava na configuração do windows 8.

O servidor não interpretava o projeto porque o modulo de Asp.net do IIS não estava habilitado, segundo a própria documentação da microsoft no windows 8 vem desabilitado por default, assim tendo que habilitado no seguinte caminho:

**windows 8, ligue o "IIS-ASPNET45" no habilitar/desabilitar recursos do windows, e dentro da opção "serviço de informação internet -> serviço world wide web ->recursos de desenvolvimento de aplicativos -> ASP.NET 4.5"**

> or Windows 8 client computers, turn on "IIS-ASPNET45" in "Turn Windows
>   Features On/Off" under "Internet Information Services-> World Wide Web
>   Services -> Application Development Features -> ASP.NET 4.5".
>
> referencia https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2736284